# how can i make arraylists like this work properly in my java algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing an evolutionary algorithm but this code segment and others give an error like this:

> generation cannot be resolved or is not a field

I've done research for days but can't figure it out. Here's one of the code segments:

```
static ArrayList newPool() {
    ArrayList pool = new ArrayList(pool);
    pool.species = {};
    pool.generation = 0;
    pool.innovation = Outputs;
    pool.currentSpecies = 1;
    pool.currentGenome = 1;
    pool.currentFrame = 0;
    pool.maxFitness = 0;

    return pool;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should learn how to use collections before trying to solve something using them. Read some tutorials first, like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_list_interface.htm).

Comment: If `generation` is not a field, then it means that your `ArrayList` does not have a field with the identifer `generation`.  Are you maybe accustomed to Javascript?  Java doesn't work that way.

Comment: well it refers to pool.generation, is there a way to adds the field correctly?

Comment: What is your example code trying to do, by the way? It is very far from compiling.

Comment: the code in general creates pools 1s and 0s. It goes through genomes tossing bad bits out and recycling the good bits to create a perfect generation. this cycle repeats over and over and creates a smart AI.

Comment: ...so it's a chromosome for a genetic algorithm?

Comment: would it help to upload the full code? Warning: 1156 lines of code!

Comment: u cant create this type of arraylist in java as per my knowledge